# Debugger only stops at breakpoints, will not "step over"

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm trying to debug code that I've built from source. It is started with the wrapper from Tanuki.

I'm debugging inside IntelliJ idea but I'm not sure that is the problem.

The debugger correctly stops at all lines where I've put a break point but never else so F8, "step over" doesn't work. Very tiresome as I have to put break points every where :)

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There's  no such thing as abviously :) Sorry. Yeah, I meant "step over" and I have changed it. "step over" normally gets you to the next line that is going to be executed but steps over method calls as opposed to "step into" that steps into methods (if there is a method call on the current line)

Comment: Why do you mention the wrapper by Tanuki?  Is it something that modifies IntelliJ?  Did you try the debugger on a tiny project?

Comment: The debugger normally works great even in huge projects. It even works now, just that it doesn't stop at the next line when pressing F8. Variables and their values work fine, and the debugger stops at the correct line when using break points.

Comment: Probably a dumb question but here goes ... Can you check whether the active key map is IntelliJ or Eclipse ?

Comment: It's IntelliJ and has always been.

Comment: Hey Andreas, I' having the same issue. have you actually been able to resolve it?

Comment: No. It hasn't happened in a while but I never resolved it.

Comment: is your application multi-threading? if yes, read more about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784413/how-to-debug-a-multi-threaded-app-in-intellij

Answer (score 2):

How do you build the project? If you build it with Ant or some other tool, make sure that compilation is performed with debug info enabled (debug=true for Ant javac task). Obfuscation and bytecode instrumentation during the build can also affect the possibility to debug. If you run under some non-standard JVM, it may also cause such problem.

When performing remote debug, ensure the target process is started with the correct JVM options suggested in the IntelliJ IDEA Remote debug configuration. Your wrapper configuration may pass them incorrectly.

Comment: If it wasn't built with debug=true would it be possible to have the debugger stop at break points?

Comment: Yes, stopping on breakpoints works even without debug info. Stepping should also work, but it's recommended to ensure that it's enabled.

Comment: I've checked and debug is enabled in build.xml I've also checked on the JVM options and they are identical.

Comment: Try to prepare a small isolated project to reproduce this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have a different jar on the classpath (other than the project) with the same classes. You could be stepping through the compiled classes and "breakpointing" in the sources.

Comment: This is a good answer and was accurate for the symptom in my case. Somehow added up with one of my projects jars on the classpath as well as the project source itself.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/267022. Basically there's another lib in the classpath confusing the debugger. Simply find out which library it is by stepping into during the debug. Then find it on the project and delete it.

In my case, it was an auto generated file that was causing the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

happened to me as well, on Eclipse (Mars).

Restart of eclipse solved it... as simple as that...

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem.Below trick worked for me:

Delete the settings for Intellij
Windows User :C:\Users{username}.IntelliJIdea14
This will restart the Intellij for you from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I also had the same behavior and I got it fixed by installing the latest IntelliJ after removing/rename the folders found in these locations https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519

I had to delet all the versions I previously installed. Just give it a try.