# Breakpoint on exception seems broken in Android Studio

Tags: exception, android-studio, breakpoints

According to [this](http://www.restlessprogrammer.com/2013/09/triggered-breakpoints-in-android-studio.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718958/android-studio-ide-break-on-exception), it should be easy to have Android Studio break on an uncaught exception. However, whatever I try, I seem not to get it working.

I set the "Class Filter" on my Activity, but the app just crashes on an uncaught exception, no breakpoint triggered.

[image: breakpoint config window]

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the exception being raised is from the class that you've specified in the class filter?

Try configuring to break on all exceptions without the class filter enabled to validate that it's actually the specified class raising the exception: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28862538/3063884

Comment: Yes, if I select "all exceptions" it does break. But, it also breaks on exceptions that are caught inside my class. Apparently, the exception I want to see *is* caught, somewhere in the system. For, now I work with 'all exceptions`.

Comment: Interesting... because in your Breakpoints screen-dump, you've got both 'Caught exception' and 'Uncaught exception' checked, so it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get the debugger to stop for anything until I clicked on the app folder in the project view (one level below root). Clicking on the Root folder of the project didn't work either.