# How do I properly set an exception breakpoint in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been trying for months to get my debugger to break on my own code, with no success. Every uncaught exception breaks in the ZygoteInit.run() method.

Here is a list of actions I've taken.

1. Added `debug { debuggable true }` to my app module's build.gradle file
2. Manually added `debuggable="true"` to my AndroidManifest.xml file
3. Checked the `Any exception` checkbox in the Breakpoints window
4. Added relevant class filter patterns to the `Any exception` breakpoint

   - this causes the debugger to completely skip all uncaught exceptions

I have been debugging by looking at the stack trace in Logcat, which does show my classes in the stack trace.

I have seen this version on current & previous builds in the stable AND canary channels.

Is there something here I'm missing?

EDIT: Just to clarify for people, the issue was that **I had the "Caught exception" box unchecked.** Checking this box fixed my issue.

Here is the relevant part of my Gradle file, if it helps at all.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.--redacted--"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 30
        versionName "0.0.30"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/beans.xml'
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my Breakpoints window.

[image: Breakpoints window]

Comment: Can't you just add try/catch blocks everywhere to narrow down where the exception is happening, then just put a break point in and debug the code once you've narrowed it down to a specific block of code?

Comment: @Fahim that did not address my question. That link doesn't mention exception breakpoints in any detail.

Comment: @DanielNugent my codebase is quite large. That is not a realistic solution. I was hoping the debug tools would just work as advertised.

Comment: To ask the stupid but necessary questions, you're clicking the debug button rather than the run button right?  And you're using a debuggable build variant?

Comment: Haha, yes I am doing both of those things. Thanks for checking, though! Sometimes it is the stupid things...

Comment: @nasch I've added the relevant part of my gradle file.

Comment: I think you need a `debug` build type.  `release` isn't debuggable, and I don't know that you can override that with other settings (nor would it be a good idea to do it that way).

Comment: The default gradle settings include a debug build type with debuggable set to true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A couple more things to ensure:

- Suspend set to all
- Notifications on:

  - *Caught exception* if exceptions that have error handling defined are to be caught
  - *Uncaught exceptions* if exceptions that are not handled are to be caught
- Set the class filters to restrict to include only your code, Android code, and Java code

See more detailed instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28862538/3063884

[image: Breakpoints dialog]

This approach catches all exceptions that are raised (when 'caught' and 'uncaught' are checked). Thus all internal exceptions are raised. The specification of a class filter restricts this by excluding some of these exceptions. For example, in the screen-dump above, the `ClassNotFoundException`, which is raised frequently during start-up, is ignored.

A small downside of this approach is that during app start-up, there may be a message indicating "Cannot find source class for current stack frame". This is because not all of the source code has been loaded yet. This will only occur once during start-up and can safely be ignored. An alternative approach to avoid this (if there are no exceptions expected during app start-up) is to 'Run' [image: Run] the application (as opposed to starting 'Debug'), and then manually attach the app to the debugger via *Run* -> *Attach debugger to Android process* ... or by pressing the [image: Attach] button in the toolbar.

Comment: There is no way to do this without breaking on caught exceptions?

Comment: Yes there is - in the dialog above, uncheck "Caught exception" under Notifications.

Comment: I think that may be what is causing my inability to break in my own code. Since all exceptions in Android are caught in ZygoteInit.run()

Comment: Are you able to start with debugging, put breakpoint somewhere in your init code, and have it break on that code (i.e. before any exception occurs)? Is this in your own code or an included library where exceptions are not being caught properly?

Comment: Yes, I am able to catch at Method Breakpoints. I am not able to break at my own code or libraries.

Comment: Adding that suspend condition produces the following error: "Problem processing VM event:
Breakpoint: 'Any exception'
Error: Failed to evaluate breakpoint condition
'!(this instanceof java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)'
Reason: Cannot find source class for current stack frame
Would you like to stop at the breakpoint?"

Comment: RE:  '!(this instanceof java.lang.ClassNotFoundException)' -- I usually get that the first time I start the app, but then not afterwards. It does't occur if starting in 'run mode', and then attaching the debugger.

Comment: For detailing the dialog with all its parts and checkboxes +1

Comment: @JeremyWhite same problem with Zygote and I finally got it working. I checked the other stuff under "java ex bp" called "exception breakpoints" in that page you have "when thrown". This in combination with "suspend all" gives a workable call stack ! phew... damn Android...

Answer (score 1):

*You need to attach the debugger to a running process*

You don't always have to restart your app to debug it.
To debug an app that you're already running:

1. Click Attach debugger to Android proccess
2. In the Choose Process window, select the device and app you want to attach the debugger to
3. To open the Debug tool window, click Debug

   *`To view and configure the breakpoints settings, click View Breakpoints  on the left side of the Debug tool window. The Breakpoints window appears, and there you could configure them.`*

There are three main types of Exceptions:

1. Checked execptions: which have to be handled by the code.
   These represent avoidable exceptional conditions which can
   be handled and recovered from.
2. Runtime Exceptions: which need not be handled by the
   code. These represent unexpected exceptional conditions
   which can be handled but not necessarily recover from.
3. Errors: which need not be handled by the code. These
   represent severe unexpected exceptional conditions which
   shud not be attempted to handle.

Comment: I am attached to the process, as I have clicked the debug icon and can stop at method breakpoints while running the app.

Comment: Yes I did, I think I outlined that in the question above.

Comment: With all the checkboxes like the caught exceptions and uncaught Exceptions ticks?

Comment: No. To be clear, the answer from CJBS is what solved my issue. I was asking for more explanation within his answer.

Comment: Regardless who did what faster, CJBS's post is what ultimately helped me fix the issue. Your answer did not make any reference to breaking at Caught Exceptions before his answer did.

Comment: The description describing how to check basics, with an explanation, will be useful to someone though. +1