# Android Studio Cannot validate breakpoints

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, adb, android-proguard

I have `SomeActivity` that extends `BaseActivity` that extends `Activity`.

When I put breakpoints into Android Studio, it keeps them red with no either cross or checkmark.

EDIT: The breakpoints are not validated, but they work when the activity comes to that point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I properly set an exception breakpoint in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138227/how-do-i-properly-set-an-exception-breakpoint-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is with proguard.

The solution was to put one debug point into onCreate method, and then other debug points will be validated.