# When Debug, geting suspended.. How to resolve this?

Tags: java

I am trying to Debug Javal Class but always it is returning this only when i debug. How to resolve this??

```
com.test.testCase.SanitySuite at localhost:53976    
    Thread [main] (Suspended (exception ClassNotFoundException))    
        owns: Launcher$ExtClassLoader  (id=21)  
        owns: Launcher$AppClassLoader  (id=22)  
        ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(String) line: not available [native method]  
        Launcher$ExtClassLoader(ClassLoader).findBootstrapClass0(String) line: not available    
        Launcher$ExtClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
        Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
        Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available  
        Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: not available  
        Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClassInternal(String) line: not available
```

Comment: In order to use the debugger your code must compile; based on the `ClassNotFoundException` I don't believe your code does.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch How could it run to get to the runtime CNFE if it didn't compile? :<

Comment: @user2864740 Run-time class-path can be (is?) different from the compile path. It's hard to say, there's no code to look at.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It could simply be a library missing at run-time or an accidental symbol strip, or a package that isn't being pushed correctly .. but I do agree on the missing context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pres F8, this is the shortcut for resuming a suspended thread.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your debugger is set to treat every exception as a breakpoint, but this is not a good idea, since it is quite normal for a Java application to generate some ClassNotFoundExceptions when starting.

See for example this question: [How to use Intellij Idea's exception breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567136/how-to-use-intellij-ideas-exception-breakpoints)