# How to debug a multi-threaded app in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm having a strange issue with multiple threads and breakpoints in IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.2. Code after the breakpoint is executed before it stops on it.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;


public class Main {

    private static final int NUM_CLIENTS = 1000;

    static class TestRunnable implements Runnable {
        AtomicInteger lock;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this.lock) {
                int curCounter = this.lock.addAndGet(1);
                System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "; Count: " + curCounter);
                if (curCounter >= NUM_CLIENTS) {
                    lock.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        final AtomicInteger lock = new AtomicInteger(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CLIENTS; i++) {
            TestRunnable tr1 = new TestRunnable();
            tr1.lock = lock;
            new Thread(tr1).start();
        }
        synchronized (lock) {
            try {
                lock.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Main woken up");
        }
    }
}
```

When I put a breakpoint (Suspend All) at line 12, `synchronized (this.lock)`, `System.out.println` still executes (sometimes several times). Here's a screenshot:

[image]

As far as I know, all threads should stop at the breakpoint.

Comment: What if you put the breakpoint at the line 14? (println)

Comment: I could assure you that *one* of the threads has stopped...which one is undetermined.

Comment: That’s simply because it takes some time for a socket connection to establish. And the debugger needs an established connection to install the breakpoint in the JVM. For the case that this timing is critical (like in your case), there is a JVM option to suspend the JVM until the connection is established. Your IDE should have an option to activate that.

Comment: @Raffaele Same thing happens.

Comment: @Makoto All should stop on the breakpoint, otherwise it's not a breakpoint. What is not an acceptable behavior is that some threads just pass the breakpoint likt it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Holger This is an SSCCE actually. My real code is a JUnit which starts a server, connects to it and does a lot of things that take quite some time, but this problem happens anyway after all the server setup.

Comment: @MSach I already specify which line 12 in the question: `synchronized (this.lock)`. Also you can see it marked in the screenshot. Anyway, you can put the breakpoint in any line inside the synchronized as well and it will display the same behavior.

Comment: The IDE only handles one breakpoint at a time. While the first thread to hit the breakpoint is being processed, other threads may execute code past the breakpoint.

Comment: @David Schwartz: that would be a strange limitation. E.g. Eclipse has no problems like that. And never had.

Comment: @Holger What happens? Do multiple windows pop up as multiple threads hit the breakpoint?

Comment: @David Schwartz: the view which shows you the current stack trace simply shows multiple stack traces. In fact, that view always shows you a tree with the hierarchy: “launched JVMs” → “running threads” → “stack trace” as you can always click on a thread or JVM to suspend either, a thread or an entire JVM, manually…

Comment: @m0skit0 on my computer the breakpoint at line 14 exhibit the right behavior (jdk1.7_40, IDEA 14, Windows 7, i5). Pausing at line 12 I can reproduce what you describe in this question

Comment: @Rafalle Try several times. If you want it to happen always, go to Debugger tab and switch to another thread context, you will see other threads print.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

The documentation reads confusingly, but [this is the relevant block.](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/breakpoints-2.html#d1481308e168)  What it distills down to is setting the property to suspend on threads, and not the entire application instead.  This will cause you to hit the break point on each individual thread instead of an arbitrary, indeterminate thread.

[image: Suspend box checked with Thread radio button selected.]

- Suspend Policy: All

  - When a breakpoint is hit, all threads are suspended.
- Suspend Policy: Thread

  - When the breakpoint is hit, the thread where the breakpoint is hit is suspended.

Comment: In fact I want to suspend all threads when any hits the breakpoint. Just like Eclipse does. I guess that's not possible?

Comment: In fact documentation says: "All - When a breakpoint is hit, all threads are suspended". This is exactly the behavior I want. Problem is some threads, sometimes, keep on executing after the breakpoint is hit, maybe when IDEA is stopping the first thread to hit the breakpoint. I think this is simply a bug on IDEA debugger, or JVM. They should at least clarify the behavior on the documentation, because it is simply wrong, not confusing.

Comment: The documentation (for 2017.2) also describes:

"_There are certain cases when IntelliJ IDEA will not stop at a breakpoint. Consider the following:
Two breakpoints are set at the different methods of a class, and their suspend policy is set to All.
When one of the breakpoints is hit, some step actions are performed.
If at the time of stepping another thread hits the second breakpoint, IntelliJ IDEA will not stop there._"

Comment: Even if making the suspend policy to "all", IDEA(2017.2) may still not stop on my MacOS . After upgrading the IDE to the newest version(2018.1), the problem is solved.

Comment: I still see the behavior after upgrading to 2018.2.