# How to debug Scala Future?

Tags: scala, future

How to debug code in a Scala `Future`?

I'm using IntelliJ.

Aside from logging everything i don't see how.

Any advise on how to proceed?

EDIT1:

Here is the error i get:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field
>   org.iadb.poolpartyconnector.conceptsrecommendation.RelevantConceptsRecommendationServicePoolPartyImpl$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.concepts$1
>   from class
>   org.iadb.poolpartyconnector.conceptsrecommendation.RelevantConceptsRecommendationServicePoolPartyImpl$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3$GeneratedEvaluatorClass$3$1
>     at
>   org.iadb.poolpartyconnector.conceptsrecommendation.RelevantConceptsRecommendationServicePoolPartyImpl$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3$GeneratedEvaluatorClass$3$1.invoke(FileToCompile0.scala:173)
>     at
>   org.iadb.poolpartyconnector.conceptsrecommendation.RelevantConceptsRecommendationServicePoolPartyImpl$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(RelevantConceptsRecommendationService.scala:169)
>     at
>   org.iadb.poolpartyconnector.conceptsrecommendation.RelevantConceptsRecommendationServicePoolPartyImpl$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(RelevantConceptsRecommendationService.scala:166)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
>     at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)    at
>   akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
>   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: doc$1     at
>   org.iadb.poolpartyconnector.conceptsrecommendation.RelevantConceptsRecommendationServicePoolPartyImpl$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3$GeneratedEvaluatorClass$4$1.invoke(FileToCompile1.scala:173)
>     at
>   org.iadb.poolpartyconnector.conceptsrecommendation.RelevantConceptsRecommendationServicePoolPartyImpl$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(RelevantConceptsRecommendationService.scala:169)
>     at
>   org.iadb.poolpartyconnector.conceptsrecommendation.RelevantConceptsRecommendationServicePoolPartyImpl$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(RelevantConceptsRecommendationService.scala:166)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
>     at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)    at
>   akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

My code:

```
def filterResultsWithExtractionSettings(conceptResults: ConceptResults): ConceptResults = {

    import system.dispatcher

    val mylist: Iterable[Future[List[Concept]]] = for (fieldSettings <- fieldSettingsList if fieldSettings.maxConceptsExtraction > 0; doc <- conceptResults.document; concepts <- doc.concepts) yield {

       Future {
         val schemefiltered = concepts.withFilter(e => e.conceptSchemes.contains(fieldSettings.scheme)).flatMap(e=> List(e))

          schemefiltered.size match {
           case e if e > fieldSettings.maxConceptsExtraction => schemefiltered.take(fieldSettings.maxConceptsExtraction)
           case _ => schemefiltered
         }
       }

     }

    val res = Await.result(Future.sequence(mylist), Duration.Inf).flatten.toList

    val distinctRes = res.distinct

    conceptResults.copy(document = Some(conceptResults.document.get.copy(concepts = Some(distinctRes))))

}
```

Comment: Well, just put a breakpoint on the line...

Comment: IntelliJ's debugger is buggy; I have seen it cause problems like this (`IllegalAccessError` should never happen in normal code). All I can suggest is using a different debugger and/or submitting a minimal example as a bug report to JetBrains.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784413/how-to-debug-a-multi-threaded-app-in-intellij

Comment: I don't suppose you found an answer.

Answer (score -3):

Since you are using IntelliJ, you can add a breakpoint within the Future. You can do that by clicking on the gutter to the left of the line of text you want the breakpoint to be on.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-breakpoints.html

Comment: Are you running in debugging mode?

Comment: yes i am running in debugging mode, albeit from scalatest

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem you're having is debugging a future or debugging Scala code in IntelliJ in general.  Are you able to debug non-Future Scala code using IntelliJ?

Comment: lol of course i do have no problem debugging anything expect future with intellij. Even if i am running from scalatest in debug mode. It is only for future that i am facing this issue. I wonder if it is not a scalatest issue. You know runners. I'm will try without scalatest to see.