# kafka project debug on intellij F7/F8 stuck

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-kafka

I will try to describe the weird scenario I encountered, verbally. it's a Kafka related project, debugging using Intellij. (Kafka might be irrelevant)

1. I set a break point on say `submitRequest`
2. I trigger the **bp** and it stopped on the line requested.
3. I press F7/F8, Intellij immediately stuck with `waiting for debug command to complete`.  This is weird.
4. I manually break the call execution. the stack looks like

the call stack

```
 isEmpty KafkaStream (kafka consumer)
 submitRequest()
```

problem is: there is no `isEmpty` related call in `submitRequest` at all. and checked that before/after press F7/F8, this remains on the same thread

things I tried:

1. rebuild the project, reImport the project, delete/reImport the project
2. javap -c the submitRequest class, everything looks fine

Questions:

1. why would a totally unrelated method occur on `submitRequest` ?
2. how shall I continue with the investigation ?

Updates:

1. stack filter is off
2. I am able to reproduce on other dev machines
3. once run past this method, the debug commands works fine.

Comment: Did you check you've turned off the stack trace filter (which filters out imported classes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Related Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784413/how-to-debug-a-multi-threaded-app-in-intellij)

This might simply the bug of intellij. multiple threads are running on that code, when break point is hit, current one get stopped, but some other run past the break point.

BTW, the solution in the original post didn't work for me.