# IDE support for debugging multithreaded programs in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, ide

Are there any IDEs out there for Java development that have built-in support (or available plugins/extensions) for visual debugging of multithreaded programs in the same vein as Visual Studio allows you to visualise parallel stacks of multiple concurrent threads? I'm aware this has probably been asked many times before, but perhaps new tools have cropped up since previous discussions.

For ref, here's an example of what I'm talking about in VS, where the stacks for more than one thread are visualised:

[image: Parallel Stacks pane]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27784413/how-to-debug-a-multi-threaded-app-in-intellij

Comment: I appreciate the input, but that's not an answer to the question asked. I'm asking about the existence of a dedicated visualiser tool in an IDE.

Comment: Although it doesn't exactly answer your question, we have a plugin for IntelliJ that allows for reverse debugging of Linux Java apps. For a good demonstration of the value with debugging a `ConcurrentModificationException` issue see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3_N2YBLLlU)

Comment: @DaveGriffiths funnily enough, I'm researching in preparation for building a plugin for IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question at hand, IntelliJ allows you to visually see all the threads that currently exist/alive at runtime, from the tab called `Threads`, inside the debug session window (where you can view the individual stacks that correspond to each): [Thread groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chnU0.png)