# IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.3 on OS X 10.10.3 not stopping when debugging NodeJS 0.12.0

Tags: node.js, macos, debugging, intellij-idea

I am trying to debug a very simple NodeJS script in IntelliJ on my Mac. I set the first breakpoint, where the debugger stops, and then use the step over command after that. It works two, three times, but then proceeds to complete the script execution through the very end, rather than stopping in the next line.

When I added a few more breakpoints down the road, it stops at them, and then again works for a few lines (or doesn't). I have tried invalidating caches, relaunching IntelliJ, restarting my Mac, and went through other answers I could find on Stackoverflow. All to no avail.

All of my code is run in a single thread (naturally), are there currently aren't even callbacks. What could be causing this issue?

EDIT: As per request of a commenter, I would like to add a screenshot:

[image]

The debugger stops in line three, and when I press "Step Over," it goes to line 4. Then again to line 5, and line 6 (`var request = require('request');`). The next time I press "Step Over," it doesn't stop on line 7, or any line after that, for that matter. Instead, it goes to line 52, which is the last line in the script, and doesn't even contain executable code.

EDIT 2: It appears to be similar to the issue pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850698/debugger-only-stops-at-breakpoints-will-not-step-over) question, except it's NodeJS/JavaScript rather than Java and it's IntelliJ 14 and not IntelliJ 12.

Comment: Add a screenshot of editor with breakpoints

Comment: Ok, I have added a screenshot and a more detailed description, @AntonDozortsev